# Deflate test cases

Tags: language-agnostic, zlib, deflate

I am working on Inflate decompression implementation.

It works pretty good with GZIP compressed files, but I am not sure I can test it good enough this way.

Is there some reference set of test files compressed with the different variants of the Deflate algorithm?

I mean with fixed and dynamic Huffman trees, with uncompressed blocks, different window sizes and all possible combinations of edge and corner cases. Also, some set of wrongly encoded files would be good, in order to test the error checking.

Comment: https://www.nayuki.io/page/unspecified-edge-cases-in-the-deflate-standard

Comment: https://github.com/nayuki/Simple-DEFLATE-decompressor/blob/master/java/test/DecompressorTest.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find some error and edge cases in [infcover.c](https://github.com/madler/zlib/blob/master/test/infcover.c), though many of them are specific to zlib's inflate code, conceived to cover all of the branches therein.